# C# List inside where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, foreach, where-clause

I would like to create a query with where clause which will go through every element in the list.

But I get "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'List'.

```
var result = (from n in School.Teacher
                          where n.UserID == ID
                          select n.ClassID).Distinct().ToList();



var events = School.Events.ToList().Where(xx => xx.ClassID == result);
```

I am not searching solution like:

```
var events = School.Events.ToList().Where(xx => xx.ClassID == result[0] || xx.ClassID == result[1] || xx.ClassID == result[2]);
```

Because number of records  in the list could be different every time.

Foreach before query isn't possible, because on the end of method I have:

```
return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

Do You have any ideas?

Thanks for any reply. ;-)

Comment: `result.Contains(xx.ClassId)`? If that is the answer, that should have taken 2 seconds of googling... if not, you need to explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result variable is a list of integers. You can check if your list contains the enumerated classid with

```
var events = School.Events.ToList().Where(xx => result.Contains(xx.ClassID));
```

Answer (score 1):

result is also a list. That's why you need to check like this:

```
var events = School.Events.Where(xx => result.Contains(xx.ClassID));
```